# Why wont my divs that fadeOut come back when I fadeIn?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I made an href that makes 8 divs disappear and then another div shows up. When I close the new div, only one of the divs show up.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#personBtnOne").click(function alki() {
        $("#personTwoBoxID").addClass('animated fadeOutRight').fadeOut(1600);
        $("#personThreeBoxID").addClass('animated fadeOutRight').fadeOut(1600);
        $("#personFourBoxID").addClass('animated fadeOutRight').fadeOut(1600);
        $("#personFiveBoxID").addClass('animated fadeOutRight').fadeOut(1600);
        $("#personSixBoxID").addClass('animated fadeOutRight').fadeOut(1600);
        $("#personSevenBoxID").addClass('animated fadeOutRight').fadeOut(1600);
        $("#personEightBoxID").addClass('animated fadeOutRight').fadeOut(1600);
        $("#personOneBoxID").addClass('animated bounceOutLeft').fadeOut(1600);
        $('#personOneHiddenDiv').delay(1600).addClass('animated fadeInRightBig').fadeIn(1600);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#closure').click(function close() {
       $('#personOneHiddenDiv').addClass('animated fadeOutRightBig').fadeOut(1600);
       $('#personOneBoxID').addClass('animated fadeInLeftBig').fadeIn();
       $('#personTwoBoxID').addClass('animated fadeInLeftBig').fadeIn();
       $('#personThreeBoxID').addClass('animated fadeInLeftBig').fadeIn();
       $('#personFourBoxID').addClass('animated fadeInLeftBig').fadeIn();
       $('#personFiveBoxID').addClass('animated fadeInLeftBig').fadeIn();
       $('#personSixBoxID').addClass('animated fadeInLeftBig').fadeIn();
       $('#personSevenBoxID').addClass('animated fadeInLeftBig').fadeIn();
       $('#personEightBoxID').addClass('animated fadeInLeftBig').fadeIn();
   });
 });
```

Comment: Are the classes you added in the first function (to fade everything out) still applied to your DIVs? You probably need to reset the "original state" of those elements after they fade out.

Comment: You should try to remove those `fadeOut` classes... or at least show their CSS to us

Comment: Just to be clear, on the first click it hides/shows what you need, but when you click the other link, the opposite does not happen? It  advise you to open the browser tools and debug this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you are not removing class after adding them, for example you are adding the class **faseoutright** to **persontwobox** on **personbtone** click, **but not removing the same class on closure click**

you will need to remove the class **faseoutright** before adding **fadeInLeftBig**, this should be done for all **personbox** elements.

```
$("#personBtnOne").click(function alki() {
$("#personTwoBoxID").addClass('animated fadeOutRight').fadeOut(1600);
});



$('#closure').click(function close() { 
$('#personTwoBoxID').addClass('animated fadeInLeftBig').fadeIn();
});
```

here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/vfrs0yss/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#personBtnOne").click(function alki() {
    $('.box').removeClass('animated bounceOutLeft fadeOutRight fadeInLeftBig fadeOutRightBig');
    $("#personTwoBoxID").addClass('animated fadeOutRight').fadeOut(1600);
    $("#personThreeBoxID").addClass('animated fadeOutRight').fadeOut(1600);
    $("#personFourBoxID").addClass('animated fadeOutRight').fadeOut(1600);
    $("#personFiveBoxID").addClass('animated fadeOutRight').fadeOut(1600);
    $("#personSixBoxID").addClass('animated fadeOutRight').fadeOut(1600);
    $("#personSevenBoxID").addClass('animated fadeOutRight').fadeOut(1600);
    $("#personEightBoxID").addClass('animated fadeOutRight').fadeOut(1600);
    $("#personOneBoxID").addClass('animated bounceOutLeft').fadeOut(1600);
    $('#personOneHiddenDiv').delay(1600).addClass('animated fadeInRightBig').fadeIn(1600);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#closure').click(function close() {
    $('.box').removeClass('animated bounceOutLeft fadeOutRight fadeInLeftBig fadeOutRightBig');

    $('#personOneHiddenDiv').addClass('animated fadeOutRightBig').fadeOut(1600);
    $('#personOneBoxID').addClass('animated fadeInLeftBig').fadeIn();
    $('#personTwoBoxID').addClass('animated fadeInLeftBig').fadeIn();
    $('#personThreeBoxID').addClass('animated fadeInLeftBig').fadeIn();
    $('#personFourBoxID').addClass('animated fadeInLeftBig').fadeIn();
    $('#personFiveBoxID').addClass('animated fadeInLeftBig').fadeIn();
    $('#personSixBoxID').addClass('animated fadeInLeftBig').fadeIn();
    $('#personSevenBoxID').addClass('animated fadeInLeftBig').fadeIn();
    $('#personEightBoxID').addClass('animated fadeInLeftBig').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
    .button,
    .box {
      padding: 10px;
      background: #eee;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 50px;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin: 10px 15px;
      transition: all ease 0.6s;
    }
    :hover.button,
    :hover.box {
      background: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #848484;
    }
    .box {
      width: 100px;
      background: #CDDC39;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>





<div id="personBtnOne" class="button">
  Open
</div>

<div id="closure" class="button">
  Close
</div>
<div class="boxHolder">

  <div id="personOneHiddenDiv" class="box">
    P1 Hidden Box
  </div>

  <div id="personOneBoxID" class="box">
    P1 Box
  </div>

  <div id="personTwoBoxID" class="box">
    P2 Box
  </div>

  <div id="personThreeBoxID" class="box">
    P3 Box
  </div>
  <div id="personFourBoxID" class="box">
    P4 Box
  </div>
  <div id="personFiveBoxID" class="box">
    P5 Box
  </div>
  <div id="personSixBoxID" class="box">
    P6 Box
  </div>
  <div id="personSevenBoxID" class="box">
    P7 Box
  </div>

  <div id="personEightBoxID" class="box">
    P8 Box
  </div>

</div>
```

Hope this helps..:)

Comment: Thanks Mike! This worked perfectly. I'm pretty new to writing jQuery, never knew you had to remove the class. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on third party resources, you are using animate.css which comes under this category, happy to help..:)

Answer (score 0):

If I can remember right you have to set a time frame (length of the animation). Like you did above. I'm on mobile so not much help. Thats the best I got.

Answer (score 0):

Only one div fades back in because only one div, $('#personOneBoxID'), is selected to invoke the fadein in your last line of code. Try this:

$('#personOneBoxID, #personTwoBoxID, #personThreeBoxId, #personFourBoxID, #personFiveBoxID, #personSixBoxID, #personSevenBoxID, #personEightBoxID').fadeIn();

That selects all of your fadeout divs and invokes the fadein() on all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing the CSS, but you probably need to do removeClass on the `fadeOut` classes in the `close()` function.  Or use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).  And vice versa when they `fadeIn` classes when they fade back out.